# public static Path

Tags: c#, return, return-value

noob question

```
public static Path filePath(string backupName, string pathName, string specialLocation)
{
  //finds a directory and counts how many folders are in it, output msgbox with value
  return;
}
```

my problem is the return value, what should i be returning? i have tried using a bool value and a string and an int value the error message im getting is

> " An object of a type convertible to 'System.IO.Path' is required "

the value i want to pass back would be the folder counter i have used in the method.

i am creating this object from a different method

```
ApplicationWorker filepath = new ApplicationWorker();
```

> ApplicationWorker.filePath("backupNamevalue", "pathNamevalue", "specialLocationvalue");

thanks

Comment: try to use DirectoryInfo class

Comment: Change `Path` to `void` if you don't want the method to return a value.

Comment: No .NET wrapper class exists to wrap a path, it is just a string.  If you want to return a "folder count" then *int* is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is requiring you to return an instance of the `System.IO.Path` class. `Path` is a static class, so you cannot do this.

From your comment it seems you only want the method to display a message box and you do not need the method to return anything. In that case you should change:

```
public static Path filePath(string b...
```

to

```
public static void filePath(string b...
```

If you do want it to return a value, you need to change `Path` to the type you want to return. 
If it is an integer (eg. if you want to return the amount of folders), it should be:

```
public static int filePath(string b...
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

> what should i be returning

You answer this question yourself in your method declaration. Change the return type to bool if you want to return a bool

```
public static bool filePath(string backupName, string pathName, string specialLocation)
```

If you do no want to return a value, change your method declaration to

```
public static void filePath(string backupName, string pathName, string specialLocation)
```

Comment: He mentions trying to return a `bool`